String Electrodynamics - Need Some References
I am very interested in the intersection between String Theory and Electrodynamics - classical or quantum. What are some good books, scientists, articles or even discussions that can give me more of an insight as to where exactly the research in this field is?

I'm not really sure what kind of "field" you're imagining here - quantum electrodynamics (QED) fully suffices to answer all questions about electrons and photons in practice. Which questions do you think this hypothetical field of "string electrodynamics" would be trying to answer that are more specific than "how do I get QED back from string theory?", which is part of the general story of obtaining effective QFTs from string theory?

I suppose I am simply naive to the subject. I recently read some of Clifford Johnson's book on Dbranes and saw some diagrams for flux calculations on the Dbranes. This made me think about the potential interpolations of electromagnetic theory into String Theory, especially in higher-dimensional cases.

Also, by 'field' I meant an academic subject of interest/inquiry. Not field theory itself, but I appreciate the insight into field theory.

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0403247 claims to obtain non-supersymmetric QED within a D3-brane in a D9 brane-antibrane background
